# In System.setProperty , project path is getting added before Chromedriver path in eclipse

Tags: java, selenium

Exception is thrown as

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
>   driver executable does not exist:  C:\Users\Prasanna
>   venkatesh\workspace2\TryProject1\‪H:\ExternalJar\chromedriver.exe"

for below line;

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","‪H:\\ExternalJar\\chromedriver.exe");
```

If I copy the chrome driver into project src package and if i execute the below line, it works.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");
```

Which means the project path is getting added before `chromedriver.exe`.
Can anyone please explain me why it is so?

Comment: how about if you put that into c:\ and then provide the absolute path, does it work then?

Comment: In that case also it fails.  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","‪C:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");         -                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\Prasanna venkatesh\workspace2\TryProject1\‪C:\Driver\chromedriver.exe

Comment: could you print the output of following line `System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"))` after you are just setting the property

Comment: Yes, If i do so proper path is printing. But The driver executable does not exist shows even with correct driver in the path

Comment: then it seems a problem with webdriver, could you try to upgrade/downgrade a version and check?